# In Oracle cloud, how to point SQL*Loader to an URL in order to fetch a CSV to create a table from?

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

I was wondering whether it was possible–and if so, how–to have your Autonomous Databases (I'm on the Oracle Academic Cloud) fetch data from a internet source (precise URL with an authenticating token as parameter) where a CSV file is deposited. The CSV should then be imported as-is as table.

Going even further, on a different address a list of sources is listed. It would be even more nice if that could be regularly fetched, and if a difference is recognized, the new file is fetched and a table created as described.

I am able to do the SQL*Loader stuff with drag'n'dropping the CSV file but I try to automate the process.
Some existing question/answers are from 2010, 2013 and 2015 and I'm sure there is a more recent way.

I'm glad for every hint.

TIA!

Luca

Answer (score 1):

I have a partial answer.

Prerequisite: There is a source file on an accessible URL which looks similar to the one in https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-database/adbsa/query-external-data.html#GUID-72DC8BB6-5245-4262-A100-C35A2E553F70, with headers:

```
"CHANNEL ID","CHANNEL DESC","CHANNEL CLASS"
"S","Direct Sales","Direct"
```

In the worksheet, I create an external table

```
BEGIN
   DBMS_CLOUD.CREATE_EXTERNAL_TABLE(
    table_name =>'CHANNELS_EXT',
    credential_name => NULL,
    file_uri_list =>'https://<host>/webservice/pluginfile.php/1/quiz_datawarehouse/data/<filename>?token=<token>',
    format => JSON_OBJECT('type' value 'csv'),
    column_list => 'CHANNEL_ID VARCHAR2(20), CHANNEL_DESC VARCHAR2(20), CHANNEL_CLASS VARCHAR2(20)' );
END;
/
```

Note it is correct to provide credential_name => NULL. The creation of credentials can be skipped.

But, when trying to
[browse that table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Ku75.png), the table consists not of the one row (two if the header row was included) but of those [two lines endlessly repeating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIBai.png).

What is happening here, and how to prevent?

Answer (score 0):

There is a package called DBMS_CLOUD() that has a number of procedures/functions for this. You can then create an external table based on the CSV file that you can then use in SQL.

Comment: I'll give it a go, @BobC although the main use cases covered there deal with Oracle cloud storage, Amazon S3, Azure Blob or GitHub, but not a simple CSV in a publicly available URL, or one to which a passed token grants access to.
That seems to be less documented and I have to dig deeper.

Comment: The question mark did cause problems.
It can be used as a wildcard. But in this case, we want it to be the passing separator to GET parameters.